# How correctly transfer my "methods" from component to vuex? Where did I make a mistake?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

When you click on the **"add" button**, you should check whether some text is entered into the **input** and, if so, then some object should be added with the text entered into the **input** and then save in the **localstorage**. When you restart the program, this object should return to the page. It is also possible to delete an object by clicking on the **delete button** For the component, this code is working.

**Here is how it works.**

[image]

Now I need to transfer everything to vuex. But I can't do this right. When I enter the text in the input in the console, I get the error "Error in v-on handler:" TypeError: e.target is undefined ". And as soon as I remove the focus from the input, the text entered there will disappear. Also, I cannot use v-model as it is not supported by framework 7

**How it works now**

[image]

**My code in component**

```
    <f7-block strong>
    <f7-block-title>Some items</f7-block-title>
      <f7-block v-for="(cat, n) in compCats">
          <span>{{ cat }}</span>
          <f7-button fill color="red" @click="removeCat(n)">Delete Cat</f7-button>
      </f7-block>

        <f7-list form>
            <f7-list-input
              :value="compNewCats"
              @input="newCatOnInput"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Заметка"
            ></f7-list-input>
            <f7-button fill color="blue" @click="addCat">Add some item</f7-button>
        </f7-list>
  </f7-block>


<script>
export default {
computed:{
    compCats(){
    return    this.$store.state.cats;
    },
    compNewCats(){
    return    this.$store.state.newCat;
    }
},

mounted() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('cats')) {
    try {
      this.cats = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cats'));
    } catch(e) {
      localStorage.removeItem('cats');
    }
  }
},
methods: {
    addCat(e) {
    this.$store.commit('addNewCat');
    },
  newCatOnInput(e){
      this.$store.commit('newCatInput',  e.target.value);
  },
  removeCat(n){
      this.$store.comit('removeSomeCat');
  }


}
}
</script>
```

**My code in VUEX**

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      cats:[],
      newCat: null
    },
    mutations: {
       addNewCat(state) {
        if (!this.newCat) {
          return;
        }
        this.state.cats.push(this.state.newCat);
        this.state.newCat = '';
        this.saveCats();
      },
      removeSomeCat(x) {
        this.state.cats.splice(x, 1);
        this.saveCats();
      },
      saveCats(state) {
        const parsed = JSON.stringify(this.state.cats);
        localStorage.setItem('cats', parsed);
        },
      newCatInput(payload) { 
          this.newCat = payload;
        },
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: you can pass the data to the functions declared in the store from the components.

Comment: According to the task, I need the data to be stored in the store and from the store are recorded in localstorage

Comment: that's completely fine, you can pass the parameters picking it up from localstorage or state like this `this.$store.state.ATTR`

Comment: I do it  like this.    `compCats(){
    return    this.$store.state.cats;
    },`